# Python loading sorted json Dict is inconsistent in Windows and Linux

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am using Python 3.6 to process the data I receive in a text file containing a Dict having sorted keys. An example of such file can be:

> {"0.1":"A","0.2":"B","0.3":"C","0.4":"D","0.5":"E","0.6":"F","0.7":"G","0.8":"H","0.9":"I","1.0":"J"}

My data load and transform is simple - I load the file, and then transform the dict into a list of tuples. Simplified it looks like this:

```
import json
import decimal

with open('test.json') as fp:
    o = json.loads(fp.read())

l = [(decimal.Decimal(key), val) for key, val in o.items()]
is_sorted = all(l[i][0] <= l[i+1][0] for i in range(len(l)-1))
print(l)
print('Sorted:', is_sorted)
```

The list is always sorted in Windows and never in Linux. I know that I can sort the list manually, but since the data file is always sorted already and rather big, I'm looking for a different approach. Is there a way to somehow force json package to load the data to my dict sorted in both Windows and Linux?

For the clarification: I have no control over the structure of data I receive. My goal is to find the most efficient method to load the data into the list of tuples for further processing from what I get.

Comment: Dictionaries (and JSON maps/objects, for that matter) *aren't* ordered data structures. If order matters, use an ordered structure (e.g. JSON array, which converts to a Python list).

Comment: I doubt you're really using Python 3.6 in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) is just a mapping between its keys and corresponding values. It doesn't have any order. It doesn't make sense to say you always find them sorted. In addition, any dictionary member access is `O(1)` so it's probably fast enough for your need. In case you think you still need some order, [ordered dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Dicts are unordered objects in Python, so the problem you're running into is actually by design.

If you want to get a sorted list of tuples, you can do something like:

`sorted_tuples = sorted(my_dict.items(),key=lambda x:x[0])`

or

`import operator
sorted_tuples = sorted(my_dict.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(0)`

The dict method `.items()` converts the dict to a list of tuples and `sorted()` sorts that list. The `key` parameter to sorted explains how to sort the list. Both `lambda x: x[0]` and `operator.itemgetter(0)` select the first element of the tuple (the key from the original dict), and sort on that element.

Comment: I don't see the point of using that key. Can that ever make a difference?

Comment: There are some issues with using anonymous/lambda functions in Python (e.g., they're not compatible with the standard pickle operation). I think `operator.itemgetter(n)` is slightly faster than `lambda x:x[n]`. Also: some organizations don't like the using of lambdas at all, while others prefer it. YMMV.

Comment: No I mean why don't you just do `sorted(my_dict.items())` *without* a key?

Comment: For this instance you wouldn't need to. The default key works just fine. That said, it's good to know about the `key=` parameter more generally.